# Wow.js and CSS Parallax Scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, parallax

I recently set up a page using Keith Clark's Pure CSS Parallax tutorial (http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) and added WOW.js for animated elements. Elements placed at the top of of the page (visible in the viewport on load) work fine, but anything that should be triggered at window position (adding the appropriate class of wow and the animation desired) does not work.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Do the 3d transforms and absolutely-positioned elements make it necessary to use a different method to trigger animations?

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/1yvqx53t/1/ - I'm having trouble getting it to work at all trying to import animate.css via a CDN. the JS in the fiddle is wow.js

```
<div class="title wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1s">Base Layer</div>
...
  <script>
new WOW().init();
</script>
```

Comment: I'm confused about what the problem is here. When I look at the Fiddle, it's working the same as in the Keith Clark demo. What should be happening differently?

Comment: Wow.js animations - having titles fade in, etc. It's not working at all on the fiddle (possible that the @import rule isn't working for animate.css) but on the live site, the Wow.js animations are only working on what is visible on the viewport on page load (any animations that should be triggered based on window position are not triggering). Does CSS 3D transformation throw off window positioning?

Comment: Hi @user3366357 did you find a work around for this at all?